# Need an explanation for this javascript code

Tags: javascript

I started learning JavaScript last week, I saw this code yesterday and I did some research about it, but now I can't figure what it does:

```
var y=document.forms['post'];
var x=y.message.value;
x=x.replace(/</gi,'(').replace(/\</gi,'(');
y.message.value=x;
```

Comment: It would help if you supplied some of the html for the page (the post form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my understanding of it:

1. Variable y holds your form which has name = `post`.
2. Variable x holds `value` property of tag `message`.
3. Replace `<` and put `(` in message.
4. Assign new message tag `x` to original `y`

Answer (score 1):

This code grabs the value from an element named `message` in a form named `post`.  It then replaces all `<` with `(` and puts that value back into `message`.

Answer (score 1):

It's sanitising HTML from text in a form element (an `input`, from the looks of it), by replacing all `<` with `(`...

...and then doing it again; it probably means to then replace all `>` with `)` for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

After the first line, y has a reference to the document's form with name="post".

After the second, x has the contents of the field with name="message".

The third line uses regular expressions to replace every left angle bracket with a left parenthesis, and the second does the same for left angle brackets preceded with a backslash. It seems redundant because < has no special meaning in regular expressions; the "i" modifier is also useless in this case.

The last line assigns the modifed message back to the form.

This code is supposed to prevent injecting HTML elements into the "message" field, but does this in a rather crude way.